What miniseries featured a man who was place in charge of a post office?
I recall watching a 2-part miniseries featuring a man placed in charge of a post office.

I watched it around 2010-2012.
The main character was placed in charge of a post office which had been neglected. The whole building was a mess with letters everywhere.
The main character cleaned up the post office and invented stamps, making the post office popular again.
A competing company used giant vanes with lights to send telegrams.
The series featured a race between the traditional mail service and the telegram service.

Does anyone know the name of the miniseries?

Going Postal 2010

Based on Terry Pratchett's 33rd Discworld novel involves a skillful con artist Moist Von Lipwig who finds the tables turned and it's he himself who conned into becoming the Ankh-Morpork Postmaster General. A position that has not been filled in years.




